# Glide won't load pictures Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-glide

I need images from firebase storage to be loaded into my application and displayed in recycle view

For this I decided to use a glide

But when I run the application, nothing is displayed, just a blank screen, and there are no errors

I rewrote the code several times, as for me this is the working one, but it still does not work :)

What could be causing it not to work?

NumberFragment

```
 package com.example.hotel2.number

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.hotel2.UserModule
import com.example.hotel2.databinding.FragmentNumberBinding
import com.example.hotel2.utilits.showToast
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore


class NumberFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentNumberBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var adapter: NumberAdapter


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = FragmentNumberBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val view = binding.root
        return view

    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

        binding.recycleView.apply {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        }
        fetchData()
    }

    fun fetchData(){
        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("number/")
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
                for (document in documents){
                    val user = documents.toObjects(UserModule::class.java)
                    binding.recycleView.adapter = NumberAdapter(context!!, user)
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                showToast("Error")
            }
    }

}
```

NumberAdapter

```
package com.example.hotel2.number

import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.example.hotel2.R
import com.example.hotel2.UserModule

class NumberAdapter(private val context: Context, private val users: List<UserModule>): RecyclerView.Adapter<NumberViewHolder>() {

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {

    return users.size
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): NumberViewHolder {
        return NumberViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item,parent,false))
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NumberViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val user = users[position]
        holder.userName.text = user.UserName

        Glide.with(context)
            .load(user.UserImage)
            .into(holder.userImage)


    }
}

class NumberViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

    val userName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView6)
    val userImage: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image)

}
```

UserModule

```
package com.example.hotel2

data class UserModule(
    val UserName: String,
    val UserImage: String
){


    constructor():this("","")
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `user.UserImage` contains valid data? What if write a constant URL like https://images.pexels.com/photos/45201/kitty-cat-kitten-pet-45201.jpeg? What if set a background color for `holder.userImage`? Are you sure a list is shown?

Comment: After your comment, I climbed to check my data.
It turned out I was an idiot and confused firebase storage and firebase cloud.
I thought I was taking pictures from the storage, but it turned out I was taking them from the cloud, where I had nothing.
Thank you very much)

Comment: Glad that you solved. :)

Comment: By the way, avoid writing `NumberAdapter(context!!, user)`. In this case, if a request finishes later than a user leaves a screen, you will get NPE.